# About Euler's substitutions for integration

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

May be it's asked before somewhere here. I think what I am asking is clear from the figure below.

[image]

Are there any certain conditions we choose positive/minus in two cases above? Or it doesn't matter what/when we get?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a "soft" answer.  In both cases the choice of sign ends up in the denominator of your expression. For a definite integral, one would choose the sign so that the integrand is continuous over the interval of integration.  (Although I don't know that this is always possible.)